# Debugger Atmega1280

Tags: atmega, atmel, debugging

I have an Atmel board, precisely an Atmega1280. I uploaded my code on the board and I want debug it to take a look at the stack memory.
I just have the mini usb cable for the communication.

I read that JTAG is also a debugger but I don't understand what exactly it is and if works with my cable.

Hence, my question is: Is there any debugger for Atmega1280 that work also with mini usb cable possibly free? If yes, what are they? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atmel has a number of debugger / programmer pods available. For example, the JTAG ICE mkII, AVR ONE!, AVR Dragon, and JTAGICE3 all seem to support JTAG to some extent. You can get it from [their store](http://www.atmel.com/search.aspx?filter=0&btnG=Search&site=en_collection&client=search_frontend&proxystylesheet=search_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&getfields=%2a&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&exclude_apps=1&ip=10.42.106.20&access=p&sort=date%3aD%3aL%3ad1&entqr=3&entqrm=0&lr=lang_en&q=JTAG+inmeta%3atool_type%3DDebugger&dnavs=inmeta%3atool_type%3DDebugger), and also through various distributors. I've never used any of them for JTAG, but JTAG debuggers typically give you the capability to do things like single step through your code and inspect / alter memory and register contents through your integrated development environment.

Comment: Is there a possibility to do a debug without buy something?

Comment: No way, you need an interface module to bridge from your computer to the chip (usually USB-to-header)

Answer (score 0):

I use an AVR Dragon for programming and debugging, it costs $49 from Atmel distributors. It works very well.

Comment: Is there a possibility to do a debug without buy something?

Comment: I don't think so.